# Use hibernate query with entity field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have simple entity like :

```
    @Entity
    public class University implements Serializable {

        /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;

        @Column
        String name;

        @Column 
        String address;

        @Column 
        Student student;
    }
```

And entity Student :

```
    @Entity
    public class Student implements Serializable {

        /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;

        @Column
        String Firstname;

        @Column 
        String LastName;

        @Column 
        StudentStatus status;
    }
```

Can i create **@JoinFormula** or something like that to create query , which will take students from Student entity to University entity ?

I tried something like that:

```
    @JoinFormula("SELECT l FROM Student l where l.id = 1")
    Student student;
```

but it doesn't work. 
 **Can i create query to select some students ?**

UPDATED :
**@JoinFormula never called.**

Comment: Not at all. I want create query to take student by some parameters , so i don't want to use OneToMany annotation. Column Student is only variable. I don't want to use OneToMany mapping.

Comment: Did you check here: [Hibernate @JoinFormula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980337/hibernate-joinformula)

Comment: yes , i tried it , but formula always return NULL. It seems like that formula never called.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you (or did you try) to use normal Query (EntityManager.createQuery()) to get what you want?

Comment: Yes , i can use EntityManager.createQuery() , but i want use query with annotations.

Comment: So you want the University class to have a reference to a single student?  Or a list of students?  Is there a column in the Student table which gives the university ID?  Or do you have a join table with two columns, university ID and student ID?

Answer (score 0):

I probably miss the poit, but if you just want to reference another entity you can use the @ManyToOne Annotation.

Example:

```
@ManyToOne
public MediaLibrary getParentLibrary() {
    return parentLibrary;
}
```

Similary, if you have a list you can use the @ManyToMany Annotation and then specify the correct join Table:

Example:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, })
@JoinTable(name = "MediaDataTag", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "MediaData_Id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Tag_Id") })
public Set<Tag> getTags() {
    return this.tags;
}
```

If you provide a clear use case, it would be easier to provide a specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

[EclipseLink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_JPA_%28ELUG%29#.40OneToOne) has a great set of JPA documentation and examples (even if you're using a different implementation)

Try using this instead (I assume a university can have more than one student)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="university")
private Set<Student> student;
```

And in Student you'll have the reverse mapping

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="UniversityID")
private University university;
```