# Associations on alternate keys using annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am trying to implement the following association using JPA Annotations for Hibernate:

```
 <class name="Person">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="hilo"/>
    </id>

    <set name="accounts" inverse="true">
        <key column="userId" property-ref="userId"/>
        <one-to-many class="Account"/>
    </set>

    <property name="userId"/>
</class>

<class name="Account">
    <id name="accountId" length="32">
        <generator class="uuid"/>
    </id>

    <property name="userId"/>
</class>
```

Or, I need to make annotated association based not on Primary Key.

Any ideas how to implement this?

Example taken from [Hibernate Associations on alternate keys](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-mappings.html#example-mappings-association-alternatekeys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continuous searching, I have found the two following links that gave me an answer:

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4479

And
[Hibernate @JoinFormula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980337/hibernate-joinformula)

For me it worked as:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
@JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName="userId"))
})
private Set<Account> accounts;
```